# hover colour for custom CSS anchor tag

Tags: css

The following is being rendered as layered text and image, the image which does a CSS3 animation.

```
  <a class="logo" href="/">
    <span class="logotext">Some&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text</span>
    <div id="f1_container">
      <div id="f1_card">
        <div class="front face">
          <img  src="/assets/4.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="back face center">
          <img src="/assets/4rev.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The text is being generated in the proper colour, but the CSS instruction is not being captured for the hover

```
a.logo {
  color: #f6f1ed;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: -10px;
  a.logo:hover, a.logo:focus {
    color: #16174f; }
}

#f1_container {
  z-index: 1; }
```

What is missing or mistaken in the syntax?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing brace / bracket after `margin-top`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS need to look like this.

Changed your colors so they are easy to see when hover.

```css
a.logo {
  color: black;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

a.logo:hover, a.logo:focus {
  color: red; }

#f1_container {
  z-index: 1; }
```

```html
<a class="logo" href="/">
    <span class="logotext">Some&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text</span>
    <div id="f1_container">
      <div id="f1_card">
        <div class="front face">
          <img  src="/assets/4.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="back face center">
          <img src="/assets/4rev.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Jerome Updated my answer with a sample showing it works.

Answer (score 0):

Move this part outside the a.logo brackets

```
a.logo:hover, a.logo:focus {
    color: #16174f;
}
```